# Query multiple tables according to different values and make one table's row become a column?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm creating an application that will manage a client's budget over the year. The client will create incomes, costs, and expenses for a particular month.

I'm trying to build a query that will bring all items according to each client's account.

This are the main table's relationships:

[image]

Let's say the client with ID 1 (at dbo.Clientes_Info_W1) is consulting his budget.

Some table data examples for each table:

**dbo.Ppto_Master**:

```
ID           IdCliente               FechaPpto
-----------------------------------------------
4            1                       2019-01-01
5            1                       2019-02-01
7            1                       2019-03-01
```

**dbo.Ppto_IngresosRubros**

```
ID   IdPpto      Rubro                             Estado
---------------------------------------------------------
3    4           Ventas desarrollo tecnológico     1
4    4           Ventas diseño estratégico         1
5    5           Ventas desarrollo tecnológico     1
6    5           Ventas diseño estratégico         1
9    7           Ventas desarrollo tecnológico     1
10   7           Ventas diseño estratégico         1
11   7           Consultorías y asesorías          1
```

**dbo.IngresosSubRubros**

```
ID  IdIngresosRubro Subrubro                 Valor         Estado
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   3               Renting tecnológico      8358312.00    1
2   3               Diseño web WP            6318950.00    1
3   3               Diseño web ecommerce     8996500.00    1
4   3               Alquiler de licencias    13750000.00   1
5   4               Brand strategy           2850000.00    1
6   4               Comuniaciones y redes    1350000.00    1
7   4               Mercadeo y ventas        3000000.00    1
8   3               Desarrollo modelo        2000000.00    1
9   5               Renting tecnológico      10358312.00   1
10  5               Diseño web WP            3212320.00    1
11  5               Diseño web ecommerce     8996500.00    1
12  5               Alquiler de licencias    13750000.00   1
13  6               Comuniaciones y redes    135000000.00  1
14  7               Ropa                     500000.00     1
15  8               Zapatos                  1000000.00    1
16  8               Relojes                  300000.00     1
17  9               Desarrollo modelo        18000000.00   1
18  11              Diseño de marca          3000000.00    1
```

The query I need to build should return this:

```
Rubro                              ene 2019      feb 2019      mar 2019
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Consultorías y asesorías           $0            $0            $3,000,000
Ventas desarrollo tecnológico      $37,423,762   $38,317,132   $18,000,000
Ventas diseño estratégico          $7,200,000    $135,000,000  $0
Total                              $44,623,762   $173,317,132  $21,000,000
```

So the "Rubro" field are all the distinct values of `dbo.IngresosRubros.Rubro` that the client has stored in the data table in the year we are looking at.

The months columns come from `dbo.Ppto_Master.FechaPpto`, and the values come from `dbo.Ppto_IngresosSubRubros`, summing the value according to the month and the "Rubro". If in one specific month the client didn't store any budget on a specific "Rubro" it'll return 0.

I've tried different approaches: creating child tables and relating them in the code behind (ASP.NET C# or VB), or creating iterations through logic code.

So far this is my closest approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT([I].[Rubro]) AS [Rubro] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[Ppto_IngresosRubros] [I]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Ppto_Master] [M] ON [I].[IdPpto] = [M].[ID] 
WHERE
    ([M].[IdCliente] = @idcliente) 

SELECT DISTINCT
    ([M].[ID]) AS [PptoId],
    FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, 0, [M].[FechaPpto]), 'MMMM', 'es-CO') + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), YEAR([M].[FechaPpto]), 100) AS [Fecha]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Ppto_Master] [M]
WHERE
    ([M].[IdCliente] = @idcliente) 

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (SUM([S].[Valor])) > 0
           THEN SUM([S].[Valor])
           ELSE '0'
    END AS [Valor]
FROM [dbo].[Ppto_IngresosSubRubros] [S]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Ppto_IngresosRubros] [I]
ON
    [S].[IdIngresosRubro] = [I].[ID]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Ppto_Master] [M]
ON
    [I].[IdPpto] = [M].[ID]
WHERE
    ([I].[Rubro] = 'Consultorías y asesorías')
    AND
    ([M].[ID] = 7)
```

Each select clause will populate a table, and I'm trying to relate them through iterations:

```
Dim conn_rp1 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(enchufe)
                Dim cmd_rp1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SEL_Ppto_IngresosRubros_Distinct_ByIdCliente", conn_rp1)
                cmd_rp1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                Dim prm_a1_rp1 As New SqlParameter("@idcliente", SqlDbType.Int)
                prm_a1_rp1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                prm_a1_rp1.Value = str_idempresa
                cmd_rp1.Parameters.Add(prm_a1_rp1)
                Dim da_rp1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
                da_rp1.SelectCommand = cmd_rp1
                Dim dt_rp1 As DataTable = New DataTable()
                da_rp1.Fill(dt_rp1)

                If dt_rp1.Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    For Each dr_rp1 As DataRow In dt_rp1.Rows

                        l_rubro_ingresos.Text += dr_rp1("Rubro") & "<br/><br/>"
                    Next
                End If
```

But I'm not being able to relate the date field.

Comment: The data in your image and text don't match. There are columns missing (and foreign keys). I also see no related data in your table `Ppto_Master` (which only has data for client `1`) and the table `Ppto_IngresosRubros` (which has data for client 4-7), I;m also unsure why the client's ID is in `Ppto_IngresosRubros`, when it can be inferred from the table `Ppto_Master`.

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped the column name in the example of dbo.IngresosRubros, I've edited the question and put it right! The relationship between Ppto_Master and Ppto_IngresosRubros is Ppto_Master.ID to Ppto_IngresosRubros.IdPpto

Comment: `Ppto_IngresosRubros` is still missing the column `id_ppto`, and the other tables are still missing columns. My points stand. That data doesn't reflect your tables.

Comment: @Larnu the column is there, the second one in the table Ppto_IngresosRubros, the only table in the example in which I'm not adding all the columns is in Ppto_Master, because those other fields are not important to the query

Comment: OK, what you are after here is a dynamic pivot. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10404348/3484879)